# Trim border of PNG images

Tags: image, google-maps, web-applications, image-processing

I have several thousand PNG images that have been scraped from Google, and for whatever reason, the resulting images have a thin, blue border around the top and left edges of the image.  The images are all 769 x 564 px, or 1109 x 877 px (I think).

I would like to be able to strip this blue border.  What would be the best way to accomplish this in an automated way?

Here are a few examples:

[image: 1]
[image: 2]
[image: 3]
[image: 4]

Comment: If the border is always the same 2 pixels in the left and 2 pixels in the top, you don't need anything fancy, just cut out that region. Using ImageMagick: `mogrify -crop +2+2 someimage.png`

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  I have no experience with ImageMagick.  Perhaps it is time for me to learn.  Are there any Windows or Mac front-ends that I can use easily?  I'll take a look . . .

Comment: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/binary-releases.php. I generally don't bother with front-ends, but I wouldn't be surprised if someone built one.

Comment: Wow, that was easy.  I just used `mogrify -crop +2+2 *.png` and it cropped all the png images in that folder.  Amazing.  Incidentally, the rate at which it seemed to work was about 108 items per minute.  It took about 7 hours to crop 44k items.  Thanks again.